PHP validation not working when we handle logged in process
I have a PHP website. I want to create a signup-login process. I have completed the signup process but when I log in I need to do some verification only after that it should redirect to the page where I want it to redirect.
I have the following pages:-
index.php,
login.php,
handleLogin.php, and
blog.php

I want to make the validation like this when we log in from index.php or any other page but not from the blog page, there will be a link named login in the header, and when someone wants to click from there the login page will appear and after logged in, it will redirect to index.php. But when we click from the comment on the blog page, firstly it will redirect to the login page and when logged in is successful it will redirect to the same blog page.
Following are the HTML codes of the login page:
<div class="login_form">
    <form action="handleLogin.php" method="POST" class="login">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="vEmail" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="vPass" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email & password with anyone else.</div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Log in</button>

        <div class="create_account">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Don’t have an account? <a href="signup.php"
                    class="signup_link">Sign up</a></label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

Following are the HTML codes of the handleLogin page:
<?php
// session_start ();
// $bid = $_GET['b'];
$bid = '0';

$showAlert = "false";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include '../partials/_dbconnect.php';

    $viewerEmail = $_POST['vEmail'];
    $viewerPass = $_POST['vPass'];

    $loginSql = "SELECT * FROM `viewers` WHERE `viewer_email`='$viewerEmail'";
    $loginResult = mysqli_query($conn, $loginSql);
    $loginNumRows = mysqli_num_rows($loginResult);

    if ($loginNumRows==1) {
        $showAlert = "Password not match";

        $loginRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginResult);
        if (PASSWORD_VERIFY($viewerPass, $loginRow['viewer_pass'])) {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['vid'] = $row['viewer_id'];
            $_SESSION['viewer_email'] = $row['viewer_email'];
            $_SESSION['viewer_name'] = $row['viewer_name'];

            // start
            $showAlert = "No authority";
            if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']==true) {
                // header("Location: ../mains/blog?logininsuccess=true&b=$bid");
                // exist();
                if (($bid!=0) && ($bid!=NULL)) {
                    header("Location: ../mains/blog?logininsuccess=true&b=$bid");
                    exist();
                }
                else {
                    // header("Location: ../index");
                    // exist();
                    $showAlert = "No bid";
                    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']==true) {
                        
                        $showAlert = "Unknown bid";
                        if (($bid=0) && ($bid=NULL) && ($bid='')) {
                            header("Location: ../index?no_bid");
                            exist();
                        }
                        else {
                            header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error=$showAlert");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error=$showAlert");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error=$showAlert");
            }
            // end
        }
    }
    else {
        $showAlert = "Email not exist";
    }
    header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error=$showAlert");
}
?>

The result I am getting is as follows:
loginsuccess=false&error=Unknown%20bid

The result I am expected is as follows:
When $bid='0' or $bid='NULL' or $bid='' or there is no $bid then after logged in is successful it should redirect to index.php, but if $bid='5' then it should redirect to http://localhost/ows-backup-30-7-24/mains/blog?b=5

Your code is open for SQL injections

if (($bid=0) && ($bid=NULL) && ($bid='')) {  - This is not doing what you  think it's doing... Please have a look at = vs. ==

I would recommend staying away from nested if else statements, it will greatly simplify your code and make things more understandable for yourself and others.
In your script you have a number of issues:
1. SQL injection

$viewerEmail = $_POST['vEmail']; 
$viewerPass = $_POST['vPass'];

$loginSql = "SELECT * FROM `viewers` WHERE `viewer_email`='$viewerEmail'";


The $viewerEmail variable is never escaped and attackers can exploit this.
Use the following to ensure it is safe to use in a database query:
$viewerEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['vEmail']);

2. Assignment Not Comparison

if (($bid=0) && ($bid=NULL) && ($bid='')) {
   header("Location: ../index?no_bid");
   exist();
}


The above is setting $bid to 0 and evaluating falsely. Which means it will never execute.
Use empty($bid) instead, as it does what you want. For example:
if (empty($bid)) {
    header("Location: ../index?no_bid");
    exist();
}

3. Typo

$loginRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginResult);
...
$_SESSION['vid'] = $row['viewer_id'];
$_SESSION['viewer_email'] = $row['viewer_email'];
$_SESSION['viewer_name'] = $row['viewer_name'];


The variable $row is never defined, it should be updated to $loginRow.
Recommended Solution
This is a cleaner version of your script that might help explain everything a bit better:
<?php
/* only handle post requests */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    http_response_code(405);
    exit();
}

/**
 * Require database connection
 * @var mysqli $conn
 */
require '../partials/_dbconnect.php';

/* Get possible request parameters */
$viewerEmail = $_POST['vEmail'];
$viewerPass = $_POST['vPass'];
$bid = $_GET['b'] ?? 0; // optionally set the bid

/* Fetch viewer from database */
$loginSql = "SELECT * FROM `viewers` WHERE `viewer_email`= ?";
$loginStmt = $conn->prepare($loginSql);
$loginStmt->bind_param('s', $loginEmail);
$loginEmail = $viewerEmail;
if (!$loginStmt->execute()) {
    $error = urlencode('An error occurred');
    header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error={$error}");
    exit();
}
$loginResult = $loginStmt->get_result();
$loginStmt->close();

/* Check if we got a user */
if (!$loginResult || $loginResult->num_rows < 1) {
    $error = urlencode('Email not exist');
    header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error={$error}");
    exit();
}

/* Get the user details */
$loginRow = $loginResult->fetch_assoc();
$loginResult->free();
if (!$loginRow) {
    $error = urlencode('Email not exist');
    header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error={$error}");
    exit();
}

/* verify the password */
if (!password_verify($viewerPass, $loginRow['viewer_pass'])) {
    header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error=false");
    exit();
}

/* Start and set login session data */
session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['vid'] = $loginRow['viewer_id'];
$_SESSION['viewer_email'] = $loginRow['viewer_email'];
$_SESSION['viewer_name'] = $loginRow['viewer_name'];

/* If for some reason the user is not logged in exit */
if (empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    $error = urlencode('No authority');
    header("Location: login?loginsuccess=false&error={$error}");
    exit();
}

/* If we have a bid, redirect to the blog */
if (!empty($bid)) {
    header("Location: ../mains/blog?logininsuccess=true&b={$bid}");
    // exist();
    exit();
}

/* If we get here, there is no bid and we can redirect to index */
header("Location: ../index?no_bid");
// exist();
exit();


Edits

Add prepared statement.
Using OOP interface.


mysqli_real_escape_string() should not be recommended. They should use prepared statements with parameters to protect against SQL injection.

Another problem with the if statement is that they should use || rather than &&.

@Jarryd Thank you, brother. I will remember your things in the future when I write SQL queries.

@Barmar Thanks you for revising the queries. I was also wondering why they used || instead of &&. I also want to know what should we write in place of mysqli_real_escape_string().

@ravikumar you must use prepared statements with parameters to properly ensure the safety and reliability of your queries. Anything else is a risk. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement for details. Also the Recommended Solution bit of the answer shows this approach, but I think the OP forgot to correct the earlier part in their section 1
